# Casting to char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

Let's take the following code for example

```
int number = 1;
char * charsequence = (char *)&number //casting the address of number to char *
std::cout << charsequence << endl;
```

The above snippet produces the following result:

> ☺

If I change the number then a different symbol appears.
That's fine, the real question is why do I always get the same symbols even though the memory location (&number) is different on each run? And the most important part is why do I get symbols instead of my memory address?

I assume that the casting I did is not working as I thought it was.

---

Edit: Since it's closed as unclear of what I'm asking, here's there real question:
**How do i print the memory address of an object to the console?**
*At the time of this edit, this question was already answered. See the accepted answer*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ostream` has a special overload for `operator<<` which, when you give it a `char *`, will not print the value of the pointer, but instead *assume* that you gave it a pointer to the first element in an array of characters that is null-terminated, and then try to print the entire array up to the terminator. (This overload allows you to print C strings in a sort-of natural looking syntax.)

Since your pointer does not in fact point to the first element of a null-terminated array, your program has undefined behaviour.

If you want to print the pointer value, you should use a void pointer:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&number) << "\n";
```

Comment: To expand on it, if you were to treat a 32bit integer, you'd end up with `0x1 0x0 (0x0 0x0)` as "string", and apparently 0x1 prints as smiley on the console. (That's not to say it's not undefined behaviour, but this is what apparently happens)

Comment: @JustSid: Yeah. Your reasoning also assumes that `CHAR_BIT` is less than 32.

Comment: True, it's an educated guess. But it's probably not too far off from the reality.

Comment: So casting a memory location of an integer to a char array will just return a char array with the value of the integer as hex? Is the &number being dereferenced somewhere in the process?

Comment: @Mitsosp: Any object can be treated as an array of bytes. The printing algorithm will access each byte of the array, yes.

Comment: Accessing *any* object as an array of characters is explicitly allowed. If the implementation-defined representation of the `int`-value has at least one 0-value `char` as a constituent byte, the construct is valid though decidedly odd and probably not what the OP wanted.